# Logical confusion

Tags: logical-deduction

This time, there are 20 questions, no bold or strike or anything. Just the puzzle.
In #12, another way of saying it is that 10 statements are true.

If you don't want to do that, provide a concrete true or false answer for every problem in the bonus.

I am also wondering if cream cheese is cheese. Please tell.

> Also, I like strawberries. But that doesn't count for the problems.

**Bonus**

A. Statement B is true.

B. Statement A is false.

**The actual problem**

Level: *easy-medium*

1. 7 and 20 are true, and 2 and 13 are false.
2. I like blueberries.
3. 17 and 15 are true.
4. 1 is false, and 2 is true.
5. If 2 is false, 3 is false. Also, 7 is true.
6. I like strawberries.
7. 13 and 5 are false.
8. 1 is true, and 2 is false.
9. 19 and 4 are not true.
10. If 12 is true, 20 is true, and 9 is false.
11. If 20 is true, 7 is false.
12. Half of the statements are true.
13. Either 7 is false, 8 is false, or 9 is false.
14. Statement 14 is true.
15. Of statements 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7, four of them are false.
16. 4 is false, and 14 is true.
17. 3 is true, and 13 is false.
18. The first battery was invented in 1800
19. Somehow, 14,3,9,7,18, and 4 are all true.
20. 12 is true. 5+3 is 8.

Comment: By saying "I like strawberries. But it doesn't count for the problem", are you trying to say #6 is not guaranteed to be true?

Comment: On 13, what are you trying to say?

Comment: For 18, how do you define "battery"? Is the cream cheese thing part of the puzzle? This puzzle has several unclear parts.

Comment: @Zimonze yes, #6 is not guaranteed to be true.

Comment: Oops. 13 is fixed. @Reibello

Comment: For 18, this just means nothing. Cream cheese is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True

> 1,3,7,8,9,12,15,16,17,18,20

False

> 2,4,5,6,9,10,11,13,14,16,19

Starting with the premise that

> 1 is true

We can assign

> 7 & 20 to true, 2 & 13 to False

Next because

> 20 is true, 12 is true, and we're looking for 10 true and ten false.  Because 7 is also true, we confirm that 13 is false, and assign 5 to false.  Because 2 is false, 8 must be true.  We'll skip 13 for now.

With our new info

> That 5 is false, we determine 3 must be true.  Because 3 is true, so are 17 and 15.  Fifteen tells us that 4 and 6 are false, because only three of the first seven can be true.

A quick Google search tells us that 18

> is true

So far we've got

> True: 1,3,7,8,12,15,17,18,20 (9/10) and False: 2,4,5,6,13 (5/10)

Because only one more can be true, let's scan through for some easy eliminations.

> 11 is pretty clearly false at this point, as is 19.  Leaving us with 9, 10, 14, and 16.

16

> Can't be true, because if it is true, then 14 is also true, which brings us to 11/10.  16 is false.

9

> Oh wait, look at this, it's true!  This must be our last one.  Hurrah!

Comment: Yay! Wow, you did it! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I am only gonna answer the bonus part because the actual problem is unclear. Here goes :

> We have two statements : 
>  A. Statement B is true. 
>  B. Statement A is false.

We only have 4 possibilities :

Possibility #1

> Both statements are correct 
>  If statement A is correct, then B should be true --> If Statement B is true, then A should be false. 
>  Hence, this will just be an endless cycle and so we move on to #2.

Possibility #2

> Statement A is correct while Statement B is not. 
>  This will make statement B true while statement A will become also correct --> These 2 statements then contradict one another and so, we move on to possibility #3

Possibility #3

> Statement B is correct while A is not. 
>  This will make statement A false while B is also false. --> These 2 statements also contradict one another and so, we move on to possibility #4

Possibility #4

> Both statements are false. 
>  This will make statement B false while A is true --> Both statements contradict each other again.

Conclusion :

> There is no answer (impossible) to the bonus part as this is called a liar's dilemma

Comment: That's what I meant for the bonus. It's impossible. If 1 is true, 2 is true, but then 1 is false, so then 2 is false, then one is true , and so on. This is called the liar's dilemma.

Comment: I see...This puzzle got me thinking quite a lot. Was really fun :)

Comment: A hint for the actual puzzle? I think u should edit some parts that are unclear @Alto